# Best way to find where objects from a list of lists, is contained in another list of lists?

Tags: apex

I have a list of `AssetChainModel`'s. Here is the class:

```
public class AssetChainModel
{
    public List<Asset> assets { get; set; }
}
```

which contains a list of assets.

So basically, I have a list of lists.

What I need to do is find all the assetChainModel's that contain an asset from another asset chain model. Currently, I have the following code which works:

```
    for (AssetChainModel assetChainModel: assetChainModels)
    { 
        for (Asset assetToCheck: assetChainToCheck.assets)
        {
            for (AssetChainModel assetChainModel: assetChainModels)
            {   
                if (assetChainModel.assets.contains(assetToCheck))
                {
                    siblingAssetChains.add(assetChainModel);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    
    return siblingAssetChains.size();
```

But this code is very slow as it has too many loops.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the groups of models that have an asset first, then you'll already have the structure you need.

```
Map<Asset, List<AssetChainModel>> chainModelsByAsset = new Map<Asset, List<AssetChainModel>>();
for(AssetChainModel model: assetChainModels) {
  for(Asset assetItem: model.assets) {
    List<AssetChainModel> modelsForAsset = chainModelsByAsset.get(assetItem);
    if(modelsForAsset == null) {
      chainModelsByAsset.put(assetItem, modelsForAsset = new List<AssetChainModel>());
    }
    modelsForAsset.add(model);
  }
}
```

Now, you can easily determine all models that are siblings:

```
List<AssetChainModel> siblings = new List<AssetChainModel>();
for(AssetChainModel model: assetChainModels) {
  for(Asset assetItem: model.assets) {
    siblings.addAll(chainModelsByAsset.get(assetItem));
  }
}
```

This changes your performance characteristics from O(n<sup>2</sup>) (exponential execution time) to just O(n) (linear scale time).